# java library path in gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, java-native-interface

I'm using jni with Kotlin and build with gradle, and have a hard time setting the library path correctly in order to get my program to run.

What is the correct way of setting the java library path in build.gradle.kts?

Comment: What do you mean java library? Perhaps a local folder with jar files inside?

Comment: I mean that I have a library that I am loading with System.loadLibrary(). I am calling functions in this library through jni.

Comment: Could you add an example? Are you using System.loadLibrary() in the build.gradle.kts or in the source code?

Comment: Sure, here's an example calling System.loadLibrary() from Kotlin source: class Library { init { System.loadLibrary("mylibrary" } }, which should load libmylibrary.so